# Magento 2: Unable to Save Custom Order Attribute Programatically

Tags: orders, custom-attributes, magento-2.1.7

I have added one custom attribute to order. but i am not able to save it from my custom file programatically.

```
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId(000000004);
$dat = $order->getData();
$order->setData('is_send_review',1);
$order->save();
```

I am able to print array of order by $dat, but when i am going to save it's gives internal server error.

Comment: It is your new attribute ? and did you flush the cache ?

Answer (score 2):

**First flush the cache  from var/cache  and using php bin/magento cache:flush**
Remove `use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order;`

then try this code:

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $_objectManager ->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
$order->loadByIncrementId('000000004');
if($order->getId()){
$order->setData('is_send_review',1);
$order->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try** `$order->setIsSendReview(1);`

**instead of** `$order->setData('is_send_review',1);`

Hope it works :)

Comment: I have also tried it but not working. BTW i am doing this from 1 custom file in magento root.

Comment: Did you check that order attribute is shown in `$dat` object ?

Comment: Yes i have checked that it's giving all information for order.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is considering the EAV model for the sales entities deprecated quite for a long time since now (starting with some old versions of Magento 1 as well) but they don't force you not to use it.
Thereby, in the `eav_entity_type` table you have a code for `order` as well.

For the sales entities, Magento default is using the flat tables. There are no EAV attributes for orders/invoices/cm/shipments.

The sales tables are flat tables so you may add your custom field as a separate column in `sales_order` via an InstallSchema/UpgradeSchema script.

Hope it helps,